# tensorflow.keras: evaluate_generator vs. predict_generator different results/accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I code is in tensorflow.keras. When I run "evaluate_generator" the results (accuracy) is different that "predict_generator". (evaluate_generator seems to give the right accuracy)

Here is some lines of the code:

```
model.load_weights(bestmodel_w)

val_score = model.evaluate_generator(valid_generator,valid_generator.n)
print("Validation Accuracy = ",val_score[1])
```

vs.

```
pred = model.predict_generator(test_generator,steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST,
            workers=0,
            use_multiprocessing=False,
            verbose=0)

p_labels = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)

print('Recognition Rate:', 100*float(sum(real_labels == p_labels))/float(len(p_labels)))
```

and here is:

```
valid_generator = datagen_train.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_dir,
    target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    #class_mode="binary",
    shuffle=False,
    subset='validation',
    seed=42
)

test_generator = datagen_test.flow_from_directory(
        directory=wsi_dir,
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        color_mode="rgb",
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode=None,
        #class_mode="categorical",
        shuffle=False,
        seed=42
    )
```

Comment: I don't see where you are computing accuracy in the predict_generator case

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro added!

Comment: What do you mean by "accuracy is different" ? You have a test data set (test_generator) that is different than the validation data set (valid_generator) since both of them are reading from different directories, so the accuracy is expected to be different.